# Why is binary search function not working when values on pointers are compared instead of the pointers themselves?

Tags: c

I was making this binary search function in c, but have encountered a problem. I have passed a pointer of a sorted array, its (size-1) and the number to be searched. When I try to compare values at the front position and last position in the while loop, its not working for the values on the right of middle element. For eg, if I pass a array={1,2,3,4,5} for {1,2,3}, the function works fine, however for {4,5} the loop just runs once and exits.
There's one more issue, this problem only happens if we compare the values on the address of the pointers, but if I compare the pointers instead, the function works perfectly. Better explained in the code given below.

```
int binarysearch(int*p,int r,int num){
    //p is pointer of an array, r is the (sizeof(array)-1), num is the number to be searched
    int *mid;
    while(*p<=*(p+r)){//if we replace the condition with(p<=(p+r)) the function works
        mid=(p+(r/2));
        printf("1 ");
        if(*mid==num)
            return *mid;
        if(*mid<num)
            p=mid+1;
        else
            r=((r/2)-1);  
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: those are 3 very different languages tagged,  pick the one you are really interested in (hint: that is not c# code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the way you calculate the `mid` value.

In the first iteration, `mid=(p+(r/2))` will give you the middle term correctly. Let say r=5, and that in the first iteration we got `*mid<num` so now p=mid+1 or p=p+3.
The problem now is that r is still 5 so the array pointer just got shifted away from its values without marking the new end. This can easily lead to segmentation fault if you will try to use your result address later.

the solution is simple: don't calculate the `mid` position with a pointer and int. Use two pointers to mark the search bounders or two integers to mark their indexes.
You can also use your way, but be sure to update r size **every iteration**.

First option - using indexes (my choice if I had to make one):

```
int binarysearch(int*p,int r,int num){
    int mid;
    int a=0;
    while(a<=r) {
        mid=(a+r)/2;
        printf("1 ");
        if(p[mid]==num)
            return *mid;
        else if(p[mid]<num)
            a=mid+1;
        else if(a==r)
            break;
        else
            r=mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Second option - your fixed version:

```
int binarysearch(int*p,int r,int num){
    int *mid;
    while(r>=0) {
        mid=p+(r/2);
        printf("1 ");
        if(*mid==num)
            return *mid;
        else if(*mid<num) {
            p=mid+1;
            r-=(r/2)+1;
        }
        else if (r==0)
            break;
        else
            r/=2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: The first option adds two pointers; you can’t do that. Maybe `p + (q -p) / 2`?

Comment: The difference between two pointers to a type T is the number of units of size T. The division by `sizeof` is not needed.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the problem now. I also understood why my `(p<=(p+r))` worked, it always  compared the pointers in which no garbage values can throw off the loop.